# NextJs toruble to get big string from router.query

Tags: next.js, slug, dynamic-routing

I have link like this!

> `http://localhost:3000/admin/useractivation/mssh@gmail.com/%ecF%0d%e8%7c%8e%f9%2cD%f2%8ea%3b%07D%b2%7b%05%e6S%18cm_K%83%98%1f%b9%1c%ad%89N4%d3%e0%d9%1c%ba%8f%0aE%27%c2*-M%d6%05%cf%06%e4%d5%d8%07%3d%e6%08k4%be%fb%c5!

> I'am trying to get  values

mssh@gmail.com

%ecF%0d%e8%7c%8e%f9%2cD%f2%8ea%3b%07D%b2%7b%05%e6S%18cm_K%83%98%1f%b9%1c%ad%89N4%d3%e0%d9%1c%ba%8f%0aE%27%c2*-M%d6%05%cf%06%e4%d5%d8%07%3d%e6%08k4%be%fb%c5!

to use it later for  authentication  procedure ( to change password by example).
my code looks like this

```
mport Layout from "components/admin/layout/Layout";
import UserActivationForm from "components/admin/user/UserActivationForm";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { slug } = router.query
  console.log(slug)
  return (
    <Layout 
      title="Title"
      description="Admin"
      ogImage=""
      url=""
      >
      <UserActivationForm />      
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

if i use link like this

> `http://localhost:3000/admin/useractivation/mssh@gmail.com/eeeee
> i can get the array from router.query

[mssh@gmail.com, eeeee]

How can i get such string like (resetCodeHash)

> %ecF%0d%e8%7c%8e%f9%2cD%f2%8ea%3b%07D%b2%7b%05%e6S%18cm_K%83%98%1f%b9%1c%ad%89N4%d3%e0%d9%1c%ba%8f%0aE%27%c2*-M%d6%05%cf%06%e4%d5%d8%07%3d%e6%08k4%be%fb%c5!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> %ecF%0d%e8%7c%8e%f9%2cD%f2%8ea%3b%07D%b2%7b%05%e6S%18cm_K%83%98%1f%b9%1c%ad%89N4%d3%e0%d9%1c%ba%8f%0aE%27%c2*-M%d6%05%cf%06%e4%d5%d8%07%3d%e6%08k4%be%fb%c5!

> is  een hash code of resetCode => array of bytes.... byte[]
> I solved id to change this to a tolken! ( string)

Thank you !